# Динамические библиотеки в Golang

Tags: golang

Есть стандартный путь импорта библиотек import "fmt", для этого нужно сделать go get библиотеки.
Я же хочу пойти по следующему пути:
Собрать исполняемый файл, чтобы он все зависимости подтягивал из отдельной папки libs, в которую уже сам клиент накачает с github все необходимые библиотеки. Это можно как то реализовать? Таким образом, уменьшится вес проекта а также можно избежать проблем с библиотеками, политика лицензирования которых предполагает, что пакет остается неизменяемым.

Comment: [Calling a Windows DLL](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs#calling-a-windows-dll)

Comment: а чем ваш бинарь тогда отличается от go get?

Comment: Мне необходимо, чтобы в go.sum и go.mod не было мусорных зависимостей, в этом основная цель

Comment: @A.Nikolaev вы имеете в виде indirect зависимостей? просто почистите go.mod выполнив `go mod tidy`. а если хотите узнать почему та или иная либа присуствует, то выполните `go mod why -m github.com/path/to/module `

Comment: @A.Nikolaev, в `go.mod` нету «мусорных» зависимостей.  Всё, что там лежит, либо используется вашим проектом, либо транзитивно используется зависимостями вашего проекта.

Answer (score 2):

Идеология Go - опенсорс. По этой причине все зависимости указываются в виде ссылок на исходные тексты и компилируются в один большой исполняемый файл.

Одно время в Go были бинарные модули, но через пару лет после введения их исключили из языка.

Сейчас в стандартной библиотеке Go есть возможность [скомпилировать модуль в динамически загружаемую библиотеку](https://pkg.go.dev/plugin) на платформах Linux, MacOS, BSD. В Windows плагины не поддерживаются.